# Android: update GUI at timertask within service

Tags: java, android

.

Hello community,

I already looked at the forum about my question but I don't know how to use a handler.

My problem:
The GUI has a textfield. I created a service and it works. The service shall update the UI.

What I have:

- Android Galaxy S Handy
- Indigo Service Release 2

My coding:

```
public class SamsungLoc1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_samsung_loc1);

    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tv1.setText("initial1");
    }

    public void onClick(View src) {
        switch (src.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonStart:
          startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
          break;
        case R.id.buttonStop:
          Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
          break;
        }
      } 
}
```

So when clicking the start button, the service MyService.class starts:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
          Timer t = new Timer();
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
//              @Override
                public void run() {

//Here I would like to change the textview of the UI

                            tv1.setText("New Information");



                }                    
           },0,300000);     
    }
}
```

Well, I already read that I must use a handler, but I don't know how to use it. Can please please please :-) give me a code snipped how to change the textview tv1 inside the timertask of the service?

Kindly regards,
Andy

Comment: do you really need a service to update the UI?

Answer (score 1):

> The service shall update the UI

No, it shall not.

The service shall do something to let the UI layer of your app know about some event that occurred in the background. Bear in mind that there might not *be* a UI layer of your app in the foreground, if the user has pressed BACK or HOME or something.

And, if your response to that is "well, I will be stopping the service in those situations", then you do not need a service and should get rid of it. The *point* behind a service is to be able to run independently from the UI layer, for pure background work.

> the service MyService.class starts

`onStart()` has been deprecated for about four years. Please learn *modern* Android app development. Use `onStartCommand()`, not `onStart()`.

> I already read that I must use a handler

While that is an option, it would not be my first choice. Or my second choice. Or my third choice.

My personal first choice would be to use a third-party message bus, such as [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/). I do not have a sample Otto app handy, as I have not covered this yet in my book (though it is high on my to-do list...).

My second choice would be to use `LocalBroadcastManager`. The advantage of `LocalBroadcastManager` is that it is in the Android Support package (which you may already be using), and it works a lot like regular system broadcasts (which you may already have experience with). [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Intents/Local) using `LocalBroadcastManager`.

My third choice would be to use actual system broadcasts, where your service calls `sendBroadcast()` and your activity has a registered `BroadcastReceiver` when it is in the foreground. This is useful in cases where you might want to update an activity if it is in the foreground, otherwise display a `Notification`, as shown in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Ordered). It is also useful for allowing third-party apps to find out about your events, which the first two solutions preclude.

While there may be scenarios in which using a `Handler` directly is a good idea, I cannot think of any that would be relevant to a newcomer to Android.

Comment: Hello CommonsWare, thanks a lot for your reply. So I will have a look to the LocalBroadcastManager or the system broadcasts. Thanks also for the sample hints. I will try to understand it :-) Kindly regards, Andy